# how to set cursor style to pointer for links without hrefs

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, mouse-cursor

I have a lot of `<a>` html tags without the `href` attribute for making `onclick` javascript calls. These links do not have a pointer style of cursor. They have text style cursor.

How can I set the cursor style to pointer for links without using the `href` attribute?

I know I can add href="#". I have this in a lot of places in the html document, and would like to know how to make cursor style pointer for links without using the `href` attribute.

Comment: Bye the way, when you say link, do you mean like "<a id="do_some_javascript">test</a>"? Or is it just a span or div tag that does some javascript?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

in your css file add this....

```
a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

if you don't have a css file, add this to the HEAD of your HTML page

```
<style type="text/css">
 a:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
 }
</style>
```

also you can use the href="" attribute by returning false at the end of your javascript.

```
<a href="" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">a link</a>
```

this is good for many reasons. SEO or if people don't have javascript, the href="" will work. e.g.

```
<a href="nojavascriptpage.html" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">a link</a>
```

@see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation

*Edit: Worth noting @BalusC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409858/179015) where he mentions `:hover` is not necessary for the OP's use case. Although other style can be add with the `:hover` selector.*

Comment: Using :hover isn't necessary, and it's not guaranteed to work on links without a href.

Comment: i can't imagine where it wouldn't work. this is a good way to learn, you may want to have other add behaviours similar the links with an href attribute: a background change, underline, color, et al.

Comment: It's been a while since I used this, but for < IE6 it might be worth adding a conditional comment to link to styles featuring `cursor: hand;`

Comment: You don't need conditional comment - just do .myStyle {cursor: hand;cursor:pointer;} - newer browsers will ignore hand attribute since they don't understand it anyway. Also IE6 will still understand pointer - hand is for ie5 and below.

Comment: Using an a in itself can cause some problems though. Especially in IE because they trigger OnBeforeUnload even though you add return false; Even a link to javascript:void(0); causes OnBeforeUnload to be called. I had a major headache with this problem at work...

Comment: @easwee, that's true, but I like to keep ie-specific amendments in their own file. Just to for the purposes of, y'know, *hygiene* and stuff... =b (oh, and I wasn't sure for which incarnation `hand` was used. And I truly hope there's no significant in-the-wild usage of IE5 these days...)

Comment: @Alxandr IE may well throw some obscure spanner in the works - that's what it does best. I've cited A List Apart above as this is their recommendation for onclick behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't work. The cursor is changed to `text` instead of `pointer` in Chrome.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov could you post an example of this not working? That would help figure out if it is 'this' or your implementation of it that doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

> style="cursor: pointer;"

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS `cursor: pointer` if I remember correctly.

Either in your CSS file:

```
.link_cursor
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then just add the following HTML to any elements you want to have the link cursor: `class="link_cursor"` (the preferred method.)

Or use inline CSS:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how change the cursor from an arrow to a hand when you hover over a given `object` (myObject).

```
myObject.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

Comment: First off, welcome to SO, Lou!  When posting/answering, please make sure to be as informative as possible and don't forget to format your code examples (as I have done for you).

Answer (score 4):

create a class with the following CSS and add it to your tags with onclick events:

```
cursor:pointer;
```

Answer (score 3):

Give them all a common class (for instance link). Then add in css-file:

```
.link { cursor: pointer; }
```

Or as @mxmissile suggested, do it inline with style="cursor: pointer;"

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
<a onClick={this.openPopupbox} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
```

Comment: that's not normal javascript.  What is it?

Comment: Looks like React inline style syntax with click handler, presumably button role.