# iOS Safari: detect "click" on the whole document

Tags: jquery, ios

Here's a link that shows how to make a non-clickable element such as a div "clickable" in iOS safari: [how to set cursor style to pointer for links without hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409836/how-to-set-cursor-style-to-pointer-for-links-without-hrefs)

Very helpful, however I have some pop-up messages that can be cleared via a little close button *or* closed when a user clicks anywhere outside the message window. It works great on desktop, but I'm wondering if there is any way to get iOS to detect a click on the body--that is, anywhere that *isn't* the message. I toyed with something like

```
body{
    clickable: pointer;
}
```

But that (predictably) turns the desktop pointer into the hand everywhere and doesn't seem to work in iOS anyway.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I think I used fastclick.js, which, among other things, makes mobile browsers respect click events. 

I'll add that this was for a project that just need to 'work,' I've no idea if fastclick.js is a good solution for anything serious.